# Breezejs Naming Convention withtout metadata

Tags: json, breeze

I've been reading answers and the Breeze documentation, digging in the code, but I just can't make this work.

I've a WebService with NancyFx that it's used by many webapps, and I decided to go for the convention of the camelCase in json.

```
'[{"id":"0", "slug":"my-slug","name":"Slug"}]'
```

And now I'm looking into breeze and I want to use oData query, I'm using Linq2Rest, so my first attempt module is like this..

```
private dynamic GetFoos(dynamic p)
{
    //Converting the request params to NameValueCollection to be used by
    //extensionmethod Filter of Linq2Rest
    var nvc = this.BuildNameValueCollection();
    var institutions = Repository.Get();
    return Response.AsJson(institutions.Filter(nvc));
}
```

And this works like a charm when I do something like

```
 http://foo.com/foos$filter=Slug%20eq%20my-slug
```

Ok, now let's play with Breeze....So I've my metadata by hand and I've something like this

```
function addFooModel() {
    addType({
        name: 'Foo',
        dataProperties: {
            id : { type : ID },
            name : { nullOk: false },
            slug : { nullOk: false },
        }
    });
};
```

And I query my service like this

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('foos')
                                  .using(manager)
                                  .where('slug', '==', slug)
                                  .toType('Foo');
```

So this is where everything breaks, first of all since my property in .NET of my class Foo is declared like this...

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Slug {get; set;}
}
```

So the url that is constructed by Breeze is `http://foo.com/foos$filter=slug%20eq%20my-slug` and since my property is in PascalCase Linq2Rest says noupe, there's no slug property.

If I declare the `breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();` the url is correct but the data is not bound because it expects the json in PascalCase but the json returned is in camelcase

I've tried to create my namingConvention, setting nameOnServer on the dataProperty, create a jsonResultAdapter and I can not make it work....

I know I just can do this

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('foos')
                                  .using(manager)
                                  .where('Slug', '==', slug);
```

And this works but the `data.results` is not bound to the Foo model....

So is there a way to do this from breeze like:

Create the url in PascalCase and then resolve the json in CamelCase.

I did this workaround with jsonResultAdapter but I don't like it

```
var jsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
    name: "fooAdapter",
    extractResults: function(json) {
        return json.results;
    },
    visitNode: function(node, mappingContext, nodeContext) {
        for (var key in node){
            node[key.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1)] = node[key];
        }
        return {
            entityType: mappingContext.query.resultType
        };
    }
});
```

Suggestions....

Thanks!

EDIT.

Right now I'm using the camelCase configuration that comes with breeze `breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();` the properties of my model is in camelCase and the jsonResultsAdapter I'm using is this one...

```
 var jsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
    name: "fooAdapter",
    extractResults: function(json) {
        return json.results;
    },
    visitNode: function(node, mappingContext, nodeContext) {
        for (var key in node){
            node[key.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1)] = node[key];
        }
        return {
            entityType: mappingContext.query.resultType
        };
    }
});
```

I'm adding to the node the same properties but in PascalCase. If the server serves this json `'[{"id":"0", "slug":"my-slug","name":"Slug"}]'` after the adapter the node transforms in `'[{"id":"0", "slug":"my-slug","name":"Slug", "Id":"0", "Slug":"my-slug","Name":"Slug"}]'`and then I don't know where yet, Breeze maps the properties in PascalCase to camelCase because of the namingConvention that I'm using.

The query is this one

```
  var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('foos')
                                  .using(manager)
                                  .where('slug', '==', slug)
                                  .toType('Foo');
```

Comment: Can you post your custom NamingConvention implementation?

Comment: I'm using the camelCase default NamingConvention, I'm just using the jsonresultsAdapter to add properties to the json, and then breeze does the mapping....

Comment: The breeze namingConvention only applies to the property names, not resource names.  So your query should be "from('Foos')" not "from('foos').

Comment: I think I couldn't explain myself. I know that the namingConvention is only for the property names and not the resource name. `from('foos')` is correct and It's working because that's how I named the route on the server. The problem I've is the auto-mapping that does breeze. I want to send the query in PascalCase and I want to build my object from a Json that is in camelCase. That's what I cannot do. thanks...